# APEX: Hide Report region from Global page

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a global page in apex. There are a lot of regions there. When I edit another pages I don't see these regions. It's ok.

But, everything changes when I add a Report region on the global page. Now I can see it on every page I have. I cannot edit it, I see the prefix of the region's name like *Global Page: Region name*.

So, the problem is - I don't want to see the Report region on every page. I want to use it on several pages only (I've added some conditions). Is it possible?

Application Express 4.2.1.00.08

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate what you found, and it seems to be a minor bug in the APEX builder tree view.  However, the report region will only actually appear at run time on pages where its condition is met, so I don't think it's really a big issue is it?

Comment: Yes, conditions work. It's just annoying. Now I have to see this region on every page.